# Fragile frame in lyx

Tags: lyx, pdf, framed

I'm working on a document in LyX and I'm trying to create a frame around some verbatim text.  I've tried a number of different things including ERT `\begin{frame}[fragile]` and `\end{frame}` around the block and also using beamer-fragile module.  However this simply doesn't do what I need to - the PDF, instead of the frame around the block, contains two small rectangles and text `fragile]` before the verbatim block.  Here's what I've got in lyx:

[image]

And here's what I am getting in PDF:

[image]

Exactly the same result is produced if I use beamer-fragile module instead of ERT.  I'm using LyX 2.0.7.1 (updated from 1.6 today) on OS X 10.9 if that matters. How can I get the frame around the block?

Comment: Is this a document in [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer), or just a plain `article`-style document?

Comment: Note that there is an example in examples/beamerlyxexample.lyx

Comment: Also note that this is much easier in LyX 2.1. Since you just upgraded to 2.0.7.1 you might want to consider just skipping to 2.1 beta 2.

Comment: @scottkosty Upgrading to 2.1 is definitely an option.  How do I do this with 2.1 then?  I don't seem to find the right option.

Comment: I added an answer. Check out Help > Specific Manuals > Beamer Presentations. It's new in 2.1 and describes how much easier things are in 2.1 over 2.0.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.1 there is an easier way. I really recommend reading the (brand new) Beamer LyX manual. Go to Help > Specific Manuals > Beamer Presentations

To change a normal frame to a fragile frame, put the cursor at the beginning of the frame (in the following screenshot, this means after the red text "Frame" and before the "Default Overlay Specifications").
[image]

Then change the environment from Frame to Frame (fragile) by going up the top left as shown here:

[image]

And clicking on FragileFrame

[image]

You should end up with

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it does do the trick!  I had to change the document class to "beamer presentation" - which in turn changed all my section titles to include words "section" and "subsection" - I'll need to get rid of them - and renumbered all my figures using a three-part notation - I'll need to fix these too - but at least I managed to get verbatim text inside a frame!

Comment: @AleksG Note that this new beamer implementation is, well, new. So if you find any bugs or have ideas to make it better please let us know at http://www.lyx.org/trac

Answer (score 2):

the syntax

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
```

comes from beamer and it does not make a visible frame box around the content, a "frame" in beamer is one slide of the presentation.

But it seems you are not using beamer (you should always post a *complete* small document so we don;t have to guess) in which case you are using the standard latex `\frame` command which is intended to be used with a different syntax `\frame{foo}` does put a tight visible box around its *argument* `foo`'  so

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
```

is equivalent to

```
{\frame{[}fragile]
```

so `\begin` starts the group the `\frame` takes just the `[` as its argument and draws a box around it and then `fragile]` is typeset as text.

You can not put verbatim material in the argument of any command so you can not directly use `\frame` or `\fbox` but there arepackages to make framed environments which you can use to wrap verbatim, eg the `framed` or `mdframed` packages or `fancyvrb`.

Comment: Or `tcolorbox`.

Comment: Oh, ok, that makes sens now.

Comment: Where can I read what the property `fragile` means?

Comment: it's beamer terminology so the beamer package documentation (`texdoc beamer`) (It's only vaguely related to the use of "fragile" for latex fragile commands)